# External site re-posting survey results

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure why [this](http://mybroadband.co.za/news/business/159145-what-software-developers-really-love-and-hate.html) annoys me... but it does.

**Pro's:**

I get that the article links the original survey and thus more potential traffic, **IF** StackOverflow cares about it to the survey traffic, but...

**Con's:**

The fact that a lot of the results are just straight up screenshots, and I'm not sure if most of the readers on there will actually take the time to browse the survey actual survey (as it's been extracted so nicely for them.)

It might be a bit elitist of me, but I feel that most of the developers on here contribute in some way or form to StackOverflow, and by having the results of something I look forward to reading every year (and taking part in) getting cloned so easily doesn't quite sit right. I'd compare it to those viral videos you see on social networks, where the creator doesn't get the appropriate credit/views..

Whats the official stance on this? I've seen how "stolen" questions & answers get handled, but not too sure about meta data content that gets created on and by the StackOverflow community (that's not Q&A content).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data (or non-creative representation of data) is not even eligible for copyright.

You can't copyright data for the same reason you can't copyright *F=ma*; data is considered to "just exist", just like *F=ma* "just exists". It doesn't actually get "created" by a person. This is different from an answer (or painting, or music, and so forth) which doesn't exist until someone creates it. You can't copyright something just because you spent effort. It needs to be creative.

In the United States, [Feist Publications, Inc., v. Rural Telephone Service Co.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_Publications,_Inc.,_v._Rural_Telephone_Service_Co.) established this. The precise laws may be different in various different countries, though. The [Threshold of originality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_of_originality) Wikipedia page lists some examples for other countries.